# Node.js error: Http post response returns ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, http, post

I have made this POST method, where i am calling an API. Somehow, this is not working, and i really can't figure why.

I keep getting a 301 ECONNREFUSED. I am also using [follow-redirects](https://www.npmjs.com/package/follow-redirects) (Resolved similar problem in a GET method)

This is the code:

```
var http = require('follow-redirects').http;
var options = {
            url: 'api.quickpay.net',
            path: '/payments',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept-Version' : 'v10',
                'Authorization' : 'Basic KEY'
            },
            body: { 'currency' : 'dkk',
                    'order_id' : '9999'}

        };

        var quick_req = http.request(options, function(response, error) {

            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log(response.statusCode)
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Their API doc says

> Any and all communication is encrypted using a 4096 Bit SHA256 RSA certificate issued by Comodo using the protocols TLS 1.0, 1.1 & 1.2.

So I think you need to use `https` instead of `http`.

Comment: This was also something i was thinking about, but the error remains the same.

Comment: Problem already solved? If not: what are the requirements to call the API? Would I need a quickpay.net registration? How can I get an authorization key to try on my own?